# Unable to run sqlplus with PsExec from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd, sqlplus, psexec

I cannot run a sqlplus query on a remote computer using PowerShell and PsExec.

This is my code:

```
$psexec = "PsExec64.exe"
$computername = "server1"
$usr = "user"
$pwd = "password"
$command = "cmd /c"
$sqltool = "sqlplus.exe"
$parameters = "@echo select * from TEST.T1 where C1 = 1; | $sqltool -s / as sysdba"
& $psexec -accepteula \\$computername -n 15 -u $usr -p $pwd $command $parameters | Out-Null
```

I get the error message:

```
PS C:\> & $psexec -accepteula \\$computername -n 15 -u $usr -p $pwd $command $parameters | Out-Null
PsExec64.exe : The system cannot find the path specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ & $psexec -accepteula \\$computername -n 15 -u $usr -p $pwd $command  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The system cann...path specified.:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

When i run the command without variables it works fine:

```
PsExec64.exe -accepteula \\server1 -n 15 -u user -p password cmd /c ("@echo select * from TEST.T1 where C1 = 1; | $sqltool -s / as sysdba")
```

Can somebody please help me clarify the issue?

Comment: If you are already in PowerShell, is there any reason you would not use `Invoke-Command`?

Comment: WinRM is not active (TCP/5985 for HTTP and TCP/5986 for HTTPS) on the remote computers and due to the network set-up cannot be adjusted. Please correct me if i'm wrong but i think `Invoke-Command` is dependant on those ports.

Comment: Yes, `Invoke-Command` uses WinRM. If they will not permit that, then why will they permit `psexec`? My guess is that you have some quoting/escaping issues to deal with as the `$parameters` variable has a VERTICAL BAR and there is a VERTICAL BAR in the PowerShell line that uses it.

Comment: I thought the same, it's an inssue witht he `|`. Sadly i couldn't figure out how to solve it. Placing the ` character before didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the quoting I needed to do to get something simple to run.

```
$psexec = 'PsExec64.exe'
$computername = 'HOST001'
$usr = "DOMAIN\username"
$pwd = "password"
$sqltool = "sqlplus.exe"
$parameters = "@echo select 'now' from DUAL; `| $sqltool -S dbuser/dbpass@DBHOST"

& "$psexec" -accepteula -nobanner \\$computername -n 15 -u $usr -p $pwd cmd /c "$parameters"
```

Comment: This works! The only open point is though that the solution is explicitly writing `cmd /c` and not using the `$command` variable. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Yes, because using $command makes psexec look for a command named `"cmd /c"`. There is no command named `"cmd /c.exe"` or `"cmd /c.bat"`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and help. I will then explicitly use `cmd /c`.